# Laravel Auth: password doesn't match after logout

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, password-hash

User password changes in Laravel 8 after a period of time post logout, maybe a day or more. When I look into the database, the password hash has changed. I used the default Laravel authentication and had this issue, so I wrote the login code below, but still, I have the issue.

**LoginController**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email_username = filter_var($request->username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ?
        'email' : 'username';
    $request->merge([$email_username => $request->username]);

    if (Auth::attempt($request->only($email_username, 'password'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    } else {

        return view('auth.login')
            ->with('these credetials do not match our records.');
    }

    $user = User::where($email_username, $request->username)->get();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**User Model**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function partners()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\partner');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'profilepic',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'password',
        'email',
        'title',
        'phone',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

and this is the method that registers user.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'profilepic' => ['required', 'image', 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,ico', 'max:2048'],
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'min:10'],
        ]);
        if ($request->profilepic != null) {
            $profilepic = $request->firstname . ' ' . $request->lastname . '.' . $request->profilepic->extension();
            $request->profilepic->move(public_path('/global_assets/images/users/'), $profilepic);
        }

        $user = new User([
            'username' => $request->get('username'),
            'profilepic' => $profilepic,
            'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $request->get('lastname'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password')),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'isAdmin' => $request->get('isAdmin'),
            'isActive' => $request->get('isActive'),

        ]);

        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'New user has been created.');
    }
```

Comment: And now users cannot login anymore? Your login controller seems to have unreachable code after the `else`. Did you re-write the registration as well? Maybe there's a bug there in which all passwords hashes are recreated?

Comment: Only the logged in user can't login anymore. it doesn't change other users password. I disabled default registration.  I'll put the store function of UserController above. thanks @MaartenVeerman